# Mono C# Gtk# Application Linux File Type Association

Tags: linux, mono, gtk#

I wrote a C# application with Mono and Gtk#.
I want to associate a File Type with an extension to this program in Linux so that when a user tap on that file it must call my program and open up that file within my program which in a sense is a viewer.

I been looking at different examples on the Internet but couldn't find a sample on how to do file association in Linux to a C# Mono application.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a custom mime type to associate to your file. You can find examples of mime type in `/usr/share/mime` and I guess you are interested in application mime types, which are under `/usr/share/mime/application`

Next you need to associate your application with the new mime type. To make the association for all users you can add it to `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`